# action script 3 - is it possible to simulate pressure on mouse down

Tags: actionscript-3, mouse

I was wondering if is there is possible to detect the pressure (how hard the mouse button is pressed and kept hold) on mouse? If not, can we simulate it by some technique/method?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

No way, you cannot detect how hard the button was pressed.
Keep in mind that the mouse is a digital input, that means that when you click it you're pressing a switch that only has two states (ON/OFF). No pressure amount info sent to the computer. It's not a limit of Flash, it's a limit of the input device. Try open a mouse and you'll see the switches below the mouse buttons.
But as @Dennis Flood said, you can use a timer to calculate how long it was pressed (on mouse down start a timer, then on mouse up stop the timer and calculate the time).

I dunno if you have some experience with Arduino, but I would use it if you're working on an off-line sytem (like an installation). You could use some analog pressure sensors instead of your mouse and send the values to flash.

Answer (score 5):

There is no way to detect the amount of pressure applied to the mouse button or pad for that matter.
IMO the best way to simulate this effect would be to work with some kind of timer - where you log the time from mouseDown to mouseUp and calculate what this means in terms of pressure. To help the user i would make some kind of graphical indication as the pressure is mounting (ie time is spent holding the mouse button down)

Comment: this is not what I was looking. Thanks any way.